# JPA 2(hibernate) insertion duplicates of child collection while persisting the parent.WHat is the workaround as of today

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, duplicates

I believed so many people have experienced this issue stated as title and cleary expressed on [hibernate jira](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5855) and on [stackOV 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903800/hibernate-inserts-duplicates-into-a-onetomany-collection) and [stackOV 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902827/jpa-merge-results-in-duplicate-entry-of-foreign-entity) . i use `hibernate 4.0.1.Final` and `spring-data-jpa 1.1.0.M1` . the concerbed POJOs are actully  ID Generated so i would like to find out whether specific implementation of `equals` and `hashcode` can help solve the problem or i would have to find another way of generating the IDs

thanks for reading this.

Comment: How do you generate the id? When I use the database mechanisms (autoincrement or sequence) then I never have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind!!

I Had a unique on a field which was the source of the problem. And By the way i use identity(autoincrement)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```